# Is highcharts-more still needed (as of highcharts version 4.0.4)?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We've used Highcharts in version 2.3.5 in our project, together with the same version of Highcharts-more. We need to migrate now to the newest version of Highcharts, which is now 4.0.4. What happened to Highcharts-more? Is it now incorporated into the main distribution?

Comment: Would the downvoters care to reveal whether it's because of their inexplicable frustration or is it really the case that this question is not aligned to SO standards? Cause I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are links to all the downloads here:

http://code.highcharts.com/

The highcharts-more download indicates it is v4.0.4.

From this, I presume that highcharts-more is still required as a separate download.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the download builder had superseded the highcharts-more file.